What does docker compose "links" actually do?
According to the compose file spec,

links defines a network link to containers in another service.

That would make sense, except reading further…

Links are not required to enable services to communicate. … any service is able to reach any other service at that service’s name on the default network. … links does not override the network configuration and services not attached to a shared network are not be able to communicate. Compose doesn't warn you about a configuration mismatch.

So it isn't required on a shared network, and doesn't create links across non-shared networks. But that seems to leave nothing for it to do at all.
Finally,

Links also express implicit dependency between services in the same way as depends_on

So are links actually effectively the same as depends_on in every way? Are there any ways in which links change the behavior of compose differently from anything else?

Links are a legacy feature that has very limited use today.

Strange that that isn't mentioned in the compose documentation about links.

I think the reason that they don't mention it in the compose docs is that compose is an add-on for docker and as such, they probably only want to describe how compose interacts with docker and not go too much into the internals of how docker works. But that's just my guess.

links: haven't been necessary since version 2 of the Compose file format; they're only relevant for ancient Docker versions that predate Docker networks.
